# How to get a data frame into a graph, when dealing with words and numbers?

Tags: r

This is my data frame

```
id   product   cost
1    Milk       3 
2    egg        2
3    coffee     4
4    tea        2
5    sugar      3
```

I am trying to work out how to get the product and its' cost into a graph, my current issue is that it will not do it because the product column is not numeric.

Thanks!

Comment: Read about `as.numeric()` ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: df : barplot(df, xlab = "yearly cost", ylab = "product")

Comment: Hi Josh! Welcome to SO. It will be much easier to help you if you can specify what type of "graph" you want to make and also include the code you wrote that got you your error. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck!

Comment: ok will do that for next time. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can use `ggplot2` to create a barplot. Like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = product, y = cost)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

## data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), product = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("coffee", "egg", "Milk", "sugar", "tea"), class = "factor"), cost = c(3, 2, 4, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We define the column "product" as a factor, like so:

```
data <- data.frame(id      = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   product = c("Milk", "egg", "coffee", "tea", "sugar"),
                   cost    = c(3, 2, 4, 2, 3)
                  )


plot(x    = as.factor(data$product), 
     y    = data$cost,
     type = "p"
    )
```